# Android - Planning a userbar notification

Tags: android, notifications, schedule

Im creating an application where I can add appointments to a list.
If an appointment is nearby, I want my app to show a notification in the status bar the day of the appointment at a certain hour.

I used the code from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
to create my notification.

However, the "when" parameter in the script is somewhat confusing because a statusbar notification is always triggered when called.
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

What is the best way to schedule such notification?
It seems there is no easy way and I have to create a service that starts a listener Activity with a thread to loop my appointmentdates and show a notification when a date fits the current date?

Answer (score 0):

> However, the "when" parameter in the script is somewhat confusing
>   because a statusbar notification is always triggered when called.
>   Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

Exactly - notification is triggered when called. If you set when variable to System.currentTimeMilis() as in the example, it means - show the notification now.
As what triggers your notifications, that is up to you to handle. An Activity doesn't seem like a good choice, but a Service does. Initialize your service on application start (and don't forget to stop it on application exit), and let it do the "listening" and triggering of notifications. It might look as:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

    private NotificationManager mNM;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //do some work, listen for change
    if (triggerSatisfied) showNotification();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Cancel the persistent notification.
        mNM.cancelAll();
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

     private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


     private void showNotification() {
        //code for notification goes here
     }


     public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
            NotifyService getService() {
                return NotifyService.this;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok thanks, a service it is, I thought maybe there was an easier way to accomplisch this, but apparently there isn't :)

Comment: if you want to show notifications at fixed timed interval, you'll have to add some Timer in your activity.

Comment: I created a service now that runs a timer every second and queries the notificationdates in an SQLiteDatabase and checks if one of them matches the current timestamp to trigger a notification.
But I was wondering, isn't this resource and batteryconsuming?
Isn't there a better way to accomplish this?
Something like when an appointment is added, reload the service and fill an arraylist in the onCreate to loop in the timer?